# Where does Jenkins store Downstream Projects information in the file system?

Tags: java, jenkins

i have two questions.

1. why Jenkins automatically picks up the downstream projects? how to stop jenkins automatically picking up downstream projects?
2. where does jenkins stores (in the file system) the downstream & upstream project of any project? if I know this I can probably go and edit the necessary configuration according to my need?

note: the projects mentioned above are maven projects which build java code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, there are 2 ways jenkins can set up downstream project.

#### Build other projects

> Add Post Build Action --> Build other projects(manual step)

[image: Build other projects(manual step)]

#### Parameterized Trigger Plugin

> Add Post Build Action --> Trigger parameterized build on other projects
>   [image: Trigger parameterized build on other projects]
>   It is easy to configure **when** or **whether** to trigger downstream project.

Comment: Thanks @mainframer . your reply is helpful. Somehow jenkins picks up the downstream project even if I don't configure anything in Post Build Action. Don't know how that happens. When I disabled "Enable triggering of downstream projects" under Build -> Advanced section, jenkins did not trigger downstream project automatically. This has solved my issue. But still I couldn't find where in the file system jenkins stores the downstream and upstream project link for any project...

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility of triggering downstream projects through project relationships. These relationships are set whenever the project fingerprints are recorded (both on the upstream and on the downstream projects). From the project relationship page:

> When you have projects that depend on each other, Jenkins can track
>   which build of the upstream project is used by which build of the
>   downstream project, by using the records created by the fingerprint
>   support.
>
> For this feature to work, the following conditions need to be met:
>
> The upstream project records the fingerprints of its build artifacts
>   The downstream project records the fingerprints of the upstream files
>   it uses This allows Jenkins to correlate two projects.

On the maven project expand the Build settings by clicking on the Advanced button. You can disable the automatic trigger on the downstream projects by unchecking the option "Enable triggering of downstream projects".